# Convenient way to get all associated values of tkinter radiobuttons?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

Is there a convenient (intrinsic) way to access to attributes of radiobutton (tkinter, python)?

I did serious search not only on Stackoverflow but also internet, many similar questions but the answers seem to mean that the only choice is to deal with "variable" parameter, which gives only value of selected button. I would like to access parameters of multiple buttons, example:

- associated value (the value that we assign to the button when creating it)
- text (label that users see)
- state (selected or not)

I am hoping that we have quick access such as radio_button.value, radio_button.text...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over a list of the radiobutton objects themselves, and use `cget` or `configure` to get the values of any of the widget options.

The following example will print out the text and a boolean to show if it is selected or not.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

radios = []
radiovar = tk.IntVar(root, value=1)
for i in range(10):
    radio = tk.Radiobutton(root, text=f"Choice #{i+1:2}", variable=radiovar, value=i+1)
    radios.append(radio)
    radio.pack()

for radio in radios:
    is_selected = (radio.cget("value") == radiovar.get())
    print(f"{radio.cget('text')}: selected? {is_selected}")

tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

the tkinter `Radiobutton` serves the purpose of only selecting one value from a list. It is typical to interact with them through the variable field because only one item should ever be selected, so there would be no need to ever check the value of other checkboxes because they would all be implied to be unchecked. Similar to how [the example here shows](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_radiobutton.htm):

```
from tkinter import *

def sel():
   selection = "You selected the option " + str(var.get())
   label.config(text = selection)

root = Tk()
var = IntVar()
R1 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 1", variable=var, value=1, command=sel)
R1.pack(anchor = W)

R2 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 2", variable=var, value=2, command=sel)
R2.pack(anchor = W)

R3 = Radiobutton(root, text="Option 3", variable=var, value=3, command=sel)
R3.pack(anchor = W)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I imagine you will be better off by using `Checkbutton`s and storing the information in a structure like a list or dictionary. Here is an example I made of how to do that:

```
from tkinter import *
from collections import namedtuple

root = Tk()
CheckMark = namedtuple("CheckMark", ["Text", "Variable"])
fields = {
    "Eggs": CheckMark("Do you want eggs", IntVar()),
    "Bacon": CheckMark("Do you want bacon", IntVar()),
    "Ham": CheckMark("Do you want ham", IntVar()),
}

def sel():
    global fields
    output = []
    for k, v in fields.items():
        print(v.Variable)
        print(dir(v.Variable))
        if v.Variable.get() == 1:  # User has this item checked
            print(f"You want {k}")
            output.append(k)
    label.config(text = f"You want {', '.join(output)}")

for k, v in fields.items():
    Checkbutton(root, text=v.Text, variable=v.Variable, command=sel).pack(anchor=W)

label = Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have checked many walkarounds, which used extra variables to store the info I would need. However, I just expected something simple enough and it is .cget() as Bryan pointed out.